# How to run code in the background continuously - Android

Tags: java, android, networking, service, background-process

I am having a little bit of a difficulty in managing background services in android. I have this piece of code with me:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

I want to run this code in the background and I don't know what I can do. Some people tell me to use Services, but I want this code to be running only in the app, not when the app is closed as well.

I also need the above code, while in the background, to alert the user in the form of a toast when the internet is not there and when it is there.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```java
public class MyService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        //Do something here...

        //Check for the connections.
        if(!isNetworkConnected) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
             //Do something else...
         }

       //To stop this service. Call it here probably not a right choice. Just as reminder.
        //stopSelfResult(startId);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea but I have 2 questions: How to start the service in the Activity and is this the best approach for my problem?

Comment: `startService(serviceIntent)`? Best approach? Well, you're the programmer, you know what you want to do, so you should know the best. Don't make things too complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much @Darman. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use broadcast receiver which will monitor operating system's information that when the internet is connected or disconnected.
Now when you got information about internet status then its your choice that how you pass that information to your view's(fragment or activity).

I will suggest two methods:

- LiveData, this is a latest approach by android to get live data in views [Here is the link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).
- Implement your own listener [Here is the tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/).

Comment: I think I will go with the service, but I may try your answer as well. Anyways, thanks for all the help.